# expected declaration or statement at end of input?

Tags: c, declaration

I got bored... and decided to make this coding, It's not done yet but I want to know why it wont compile yet.

```
/*Coding that will countdown the amount of bottles on the wall
*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int bottles = 99;
while (bottles >= 0) {  
put ("%i\n bottles of beer on the wall, %i\n bottles of beer, take one down pass it around", bottles, bottles) ; {
    bottles--; 
    put ("%i\n bottles of beer on the wall", bottles) ;
}
continue; }
```

Comment: This happens when you don't use proper indentation. You lost a closing `}` in the end. And what is `put`? You mean `printf`?

Comment: I got bored.. and decided to skip this question by voting down, since no "search" efforts are shown.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the answer that says you have one too few brace: you have one too may (at the very end of the `put()`... Change it to

```
/*Coding that will countdown the amount of bottles on the wall
*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int bottles = 99;
  while (bottles > 0) // got rid of '='... Since decrementing inside loop
  {  
    printf ("%i bottles of beer on the wall, %i bottles of beer\n", bottles, bottles);
    printf("Take one down pass it around\n"); // <<<<removed a '}' here...>>>>
    bottles--; 
    printf("%i bottles of beer on the wall\n\n", bottles) ;
  }
  continue; // what is this doing here??? You are not in a while loop...
}
```

Note - I split one `put` into two `printf` statements and changed where the `'\n'` is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally , this error arises when you have missed a parenthesis . You are missing a closing parethesis `}` .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int bottles = 99;
while (bottles >= 0) {  
put ("%i\n bottles of beer on the wall, %i\n bottles of beer, take one down pass it around", bottles, bottles) ; {
    bottles--; 
    put ("%i\n bottles of beer on the wall", bottles) ;
}
continue; 
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes It was printf Yu Hao